# Saving an Excel value to another cell using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a couple formulas that calculate values from a table - averages, totals etc. This happens each time the file is opened (which is daily).

The issue is I want to save the 2 values that are calculated daily to another table / cells so i dont lose them. Currently they are overwritten each time the file is opened with the new calculated value.

Any advise on how i can do this would be really appreciated ?

Thanks
paul

Comment: A formula will not do this.  You will need vba in a worksheet_calculate event.

Comment: Hi Scott - are you able to shed some light on this vba script please ?  Thanks in advance